# How to select Japanese locale on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, locale

When I try

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_COLLATE, 'ja-JP')
```

I get the error message

```
locale.Error: unsupported locale setting
```

How do I fix that?
I'm using Python 2.7.3 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using windows, this doesn't work because the japanese locale is 'jpn'. Try:

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_COLLATE, 'jpn')
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cdax410z) is a list of country/region strings supported.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows you must use the string "japanese" instead of "ja-JP" as the second argument to locale.setlocale().

Comment: The string "japanese" appears to work on Linux (with Python 3.8) as well.  `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_COLLATE, 'japanese')`